# Problem dynamically allocating memory for a array in a struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on a school project, and I've come to a full stop trying to allocate some dynamic memory for a array inside a struct.

My structs are:

```
typedef struct {
    int avaliacao;
    char nome[MAXG];
    char email [MAXG];
}Classificacao;

typedef struct {
    char nif[MAXG];
    char nome[MAXG];
    char categoria[MAXG];
    char ramo[MAXG];
    char rua[MAXBIG];
    char localidade[MAXG];
    char codigoPostal[MAXG];
    int estado;
    int nClassificacoes;
    int maxClassificacoes;
    Classificacao *classis;
    int nComentarios;
    Comentario *comment;
}Empresa;    
    
typedef struct {
    int contador;
    int alocadas;
    Empresa *empresas;
}Empresas;
```

I'm trying to allocate memory for "Classificacao" (evaluation in portuguese) this will be contained within a empresa (company). I´ve tried everything but all I'm getting is stackdump errors.
This is my createCompany function:

```
void criarEmpresa(Empresas *catalogo, Ramos *catalogoRamos) {
    // Verifica se o número de empresas atingiu o limite atualmente alocado
    if (catalogo->contador == catalogo->alocadas) {
        // Se o limite for atingido, aloca mais espaço
        catalogo->alocadas += 10; 
        catalogo->empresas = realloc(catalogo->empresas, catalogo->alocadas * sizeof(Empresa));
    }

    Empresa novaEmpresa;

    // Solicita o NIF da empresa e verifica se é válido
    do{
        printf("Nif da empresa: ");
        scanf("%s", novaEmpresa.nif);
        if (!verificaNIF(novaEmpresa.nif))
        {
                printf("O NIF nao e valido.\n");
        }
    }while(!verificaNIF(novaEmpresa.nif));
    
    // Solicita o nome da empresa
    printf("Nome da empresa: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", novaEmpresa.nome);
    
    // Solicita a categoria da empresa e verifica se é válida
    do {
        printf("Categoria da empresa(Micro, PME ou GrandeEmpresa): ");
        scanf("%s", novaEmpresa.categoria);
    }while(!verificaCategoria(novaEmpresa.categoria));
    
    // Solicita a rua da empresa
    printf("Rua da empresa: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", novaEmpresa.rua);
    // Solicita a localidade da empresa
    printf("Localidade da empresa: ");
    scanf("%s", novaEmpresa.localidade);
    
    // Solicita o código postal da empresa e verifica se é válido
    do{
        printf("Codigo postal da empresa: ");
        scanf("%s", novaEmpresa.codigoPostal);
        if (!verificaCodigoPostal(novaEmpresa.codigoPostal)) 
        {
            printf("O NIF nao e valido.\n");
        }
    }while(!verificaCodigoPostal(novaEmpresa.codigoPostal));

    // Se existirem ramos de atividade, solicita que o usuário escolha um para a empresa
    if(catalogoRamos->contador > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < catalogoRamos->contador; i++) {
            printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, catalogoRamos->ramos[i].nome);
        }
        int escolha;
        do {
            printf("Escolha o ramo de atividade da empresa (1-%d): ", catalogoRamos->contador);
            scanf("%d", &escolha);
        } while(escolha < 1 || escolha > catalogoRamos->contador);
        strcpy(novaEmpresa.ramo, catalogoRamos->ramos[escolha-1].nome);
    } else {
        // Se não existirem ramos de atividade, informa o usuário e retorna
        printf("Nao existem ramos de atividade disponíveis. Por favor, crie um ramo de atividade antes de criar uma empresa.\n");
        return;
    }

       
    // Define o estado da empresa como ativo
    novaEmpresa.estado = 1;
    
    // Adiciona a nova empresa ao catálogo
    catalogo->empresas[catalogo->contador] = novaEmpresa;
    catalogo->contador++;
    
    // Inicializa o array de classificações
    novaEmpresa.nClassificacoes = 0;
    novaEmpresa.maxClassificacoes = MAX_CLASSIFICACOES;
    novaEmpresa.classis = malloc(novaEmpresa.maxClassificacoes * sizeof(Classificacao));
    
    // Informa ao usuário que a empresa foi criada com sucesso
    printf("Empresa criada com sucesso!\n");
}
```

As you can see i allocate MAX_CLASSIFICACOES (value is 10) evaluations and then i check in the createEvaluation function if all the memory is full and if it is realloc it.
The function is as follows:

```
void classificarEmpresa(Empresas *catalogo) {
    char nif[MAXG];
    int avaliacao;
    Classificacao novaClassificacao;

    // Solicita o NIF da empresa a ser classificada
    printf("NIF da empresa a ser classificada: ");
    scanf("%s", nif);

    // Procura a empresa no catálogo
    for(int i = 0; i < catalogo->contador; i++) {
        if(strcmp(catalogo->empresas[i].nif, nif) == 0) {
            // Solicita a avaliação do usuário
            do {
                printf("Avaliacao (0-5): ");
                scanf("%d", &avaliacao);
            } while(avaliacao < 0 || avaliacao > 5);

            // Verifica se o número de classificações atingiu o limite atualmente alocado
            if (catalogo->empresas[i].nClassificacoes == catalogo->empresas[i].maxClassificacoes) {
                // Se o limite for atingido, aloca mais espaço
                catalogo->empresas[i].maxClassificacoes += MAX_CLASSIFICACOES;
                Classificacao *temp = realloc(catalogo->empresas[i].classis, catalogo->empresas[i].maxClassificacoes * sizeof(Classificacao));
                
                if(temp == NULL) {
                    printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria.\n");
                    return;
                }
                
                catalogo->empresas[i].classis = temp;
            }

            // Adiciona a avaliação à lista de classificações da empresa
            novaClassificacao.avaliacao = avaliacao;
            catalogo->empresas[i].classis[catalogo->empresas[i].nClassificacoes] = novaClassificacao;
            catalogo->empresas[i].nClassificacoes++;

            printf("Avaliacao adicionada com sucesso!\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("Empresa nao encontrada.\n");
}
```

Note that creating company works perfectly and no problems whatsoever. Thanks, in advance.

Minimal, Reproducible Example (with no user input. It creates a company then tries to review it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXG 50
#define MAXBIG 200
#define MAX_AVALS 10

   
typedef struct {
    int avaliacao;
}Classificacao;

typedef struct {
    char nif[MAXG];
    char nome[MAXG];
    int nClassificacoes;
    int maxClassificacoes;
    Classificacao *classis;
}Empresa;    
    
typedef struct {
    int contador;
    int alocadas;
    Empresa *empresas;
}Empresas;

void classificarEmpresa(Empresas *catalogo) {
    char nif[MAXG] = "123456789"; // NIF hardcoded
    int avaliacao = 5; // Avaliação hardcoded
    Classificacao novaClassificacao;

    // Procura a empresa no catálogo
    for(int i = 0; i < catalogo->contador; i++) {
        if(strcmp(catalogo->empresas[i].nif, nif) == 0) {
            // Adiciona a avaliação à lista de classificações da empresa
            novaClassificacao.avaliacao = avaliacao;
            catalogo->empresas[i].classis[catalogo->empresas[i].nClassificacoes] = novaClassificacao;
            catalogo->empresas[i].nClassificacoes++;

            printf("Avaliacao adicionada com sucesso!\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("Empresa nao encontrada.\n");
}

void criarEmpresa(Empresas *catalogo) {
    Empresa novaEmpresa;

    strcpy(novaEmpresa.nif, "123456789"); // NIF hardcoded
    strcpy(novaEmpresa.nome, "Empresa XYZ"); // Nome da empresa hardcoded
    
    // Adiciona a nova empresa ao catálogo
    catalogo->empresas[catalogo->contador] = novaEmpresa;
    catalogo->contador++;
    
    // Inicializa o array de classificações
    novaEmpresa.nClassificacoes = 0;
    novaEmpresa.maxClassificacoes = MAX_AVALS;
    novaEmpresa.classis = malloc(novaEmpresa.maxClassificacoes * sizeof(Classificacao));
    
    // Informa ao usuário que a empresa foi criada com sucesso
    printf("Empresa criada com sucesso!\n");
}

int main() {
    
    Empresas Empresa = {.contador = 0};
    
    int opc = 1;
    do {
        switch (opc) {
            case 1:
                criarEmpresa(&Empresa);
                opc = 2; 
                break;
            case 2:
                classificarEmpresa(&Empresa);
                opc = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                opc = 4;
                break;
        }
    } while (opc != 4);
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Done! added a mre

Comment: The program needs input and the question doesn't provide any. It is recommended to restructure your code such that all the data is hardcoded. If you don't have a problem with reading input, just do not include reading input in the [mre] (otherwise it is not minimal). If such restructuring is not possible, include the input that crashes the program in the question.

Comment: Added a hardcoded example :)

Comment: Even the second "minimal" example needs some instructions to reproduce an error. It looks like there is a missing `break` statement before `case 3:` in `main`.

Comment: Made the "minimal" example as short as i could, it creates a company with number (123456789) then tries to evaluate it. The error is the same i get in main program Segment fault ( 0 [main] cppapplication_1 1836 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to cppapplication_1.exe.stackdump)

Comment: Great! You can use the address and UB sanitizers to try and find the line that creates the problem (I'm on mobile right now so it is difficult to me to do so).

Comment: Still can't figure the problem! I've tried all i know

Comment: Why not post this at the _pt_  stack overflow? Or use english-named variables and comments while posting here? Maybe also use shorter names?  My first hint is to not use `void`: return pointers, always.  You want to create a record for a company? Return one. It is simpler. Less arguments, no problem with scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main`, you define an object `Empresa` of type `Empresas` which contains a member `empresas` that is a pointer to the type `Empresa`. Nowhere in the program do you set the `empresas` member to point to anything.

You must allocate memory to hold `Empresa` objects, and you must set the `empresas` member to point to that memory. You will likely need to reallocate more memory as the number of `Empresa` objects you want to hold grows. You must rewrite your code to do these memory allocations.

Answer (score 1):

First problem I see is in company creation function:

```
    Empresa novaEmpresa;// in stack memory
// ...
    catalogo->empresas[catalogo->contador] = novaEmpresa;// this has written into structure
    catalogo->contador++;
    
    novaEmpresa.nClassificacoes = 0;// these does not affect the variable in the structure
    novaEmpresa.maxClassificacoes = MAX_CLASSIFICACOES;
    novaEmpresa.classis = malloc(novaEmpresa.maxClassificacoes * sizeof(Classificacao));
```

You are assigning 'nClassificacoes' and allocating after adding it into the structure.

Consider these in your project:

1. [Linked Lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-linked-list/), so that you won't have to realloc every time.
2. Separate the code in the large 'do..while' and 'if..else' scopes, create new functions for them. Easier to spot errors, easier to fix them, easier for others to understand it.
3. Test your code often and before it gets complicated.
4. Validate input (size, type, content etc.)

Comment: This is totally incorrect. "You will lose 'novaEmpresa' at the time the creating function's scope is closed." It doesn't matter because the array now contains a copy of it.

Comment: Hi, Yusuf don't think that's right, but thanks for the other tips!

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't see that. Let me check it again.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Turns out, not totally, but partially incorrect :D

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashes here

```
    catalogo->empresas[catalogo->contador] = novaEmpresa;
```

Why?

```
typedef struct
{
    int      contador;
    int      alocadas;
    Empresa* empresas;
} Empresas;
```

`empresas` is `Empresa*` and it seems that you expected to have an array there. But in `main` we have only

```
    Empresas Empresa = {.contador = 0};
```

So `empresas` points to nothing. It is not even initialized.

Comment: "_So empresas points to nothing. It is not even initialized._" Wrong. "_Omitted fields are implicitly initialized the same as for objects that have static storage duration._"